# I can't change view/angle or pan, zoom works fine

Tags: 3d-view

I tried restarting Blender, opening new, resetting to default factory settings, reinstalling blender - nothing works.

All the mouse buttons work fine, selection of object, right-clicking on it for properties/actions. For some reason Zoom works. Tried checking/unchecking Auto-depth box in preferences like one answer suggested in someone's question here. Tried laptop's touchpad to rotate or pan, still nothing.

Comment: Let's be absolutely clear, sorry if i push open doors... Is your Middle Button working ? https://www.onlinemictest.com/mouse-test/

Comment: I can scroll to zoom in and out.

Comment: Edit* Just realized you added a link. It shows the the middle click/button is not working.. scrolling does, left/right do, but middle is not. Let me try a different mouse! Thank you. IT WAS THE MOUSE. ughhh! thank you sooo much!

Comment: Just a random video because there is plenty of them, but this can be "easily" solved if you can't / dont'want to buy a brand new mouse : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2WnLqU7ES5M

Comment: Thanks again thibsert! I'll just go buy another cheap mouse haha. You were very helpful and I don't know how to upvote you or credit you here for the effort.

Comment: I'm glad I helped you, you don't need to upvote me or anything ;)